# Log4j seems not to work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, spring-boot

I tried to add `Spring` and `Maven` to one of my existing project, and I find that no matter how I configure, the logging seems to be out of my control.

I tried putting the `log4j.properties` in `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`(Actually I am not sure where to put).

But when I use `Log4j` to log, the log displays in the console only, though I configure it into a file.

My `log4j.properties` is like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1 
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.encoding=utf-8
log4j.appender.A1.File=E:\Programminglog\debug.log 
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold = DEBUG 
log4j.appender.A1.Append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n
```

I am not sure if I miss something or `Spring` overrides some settings, since I am new to `Maven` and `Spring`.

PS: Before I add dependencies of `Log4j` in `pom`.xml,no compile errors though I use `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

This is how my application.java looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"hello","wodinow.weixin.jaskey"})
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

        LogUtil.info("Application Boots!");// here this line does not show in the file
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandService commandService(){
        return CommandService.getInstance();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What server are you running this on? FYI, by default Maven does not copy anything from src/main/java into your application. Therefore you should keep log4j.properties, etc in src/main/resources

Comment: I uses spring embed tomcat, I run my Application.java as java application to boot my app. BTW, I also copy that properties into webapp/WEB-INF, but no luck :(

Comment: log4j.properties must be available on the class path. The WEB-INF directory is not (normally) on the class path. If you run your application with `-Dlog4j.debug` on the command line you will discover what log4j thinks is happening (if anything at all).

Comment: @SteveC, Would you please give me the full command how to run my application with -Dlog4j.debug? BTW, I uses Spring boot, i don't know it it did something..

Answer (score 7):

If you are using log4j with spring-boot then you have to add dependency with "exclusions" in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  **<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>**
</dependency>

**<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>**
```

Please follow this. It will resolve your problem.

http://www.atechref.com/blog/maven/spring-boot-using-log4j-logging/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

> By default, If you use the ‘Starter POMs’, Logback will be used for logging

(From: [Spring Boot Reference, Chapter 25 Logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html))

So either you configure your logging via logback `logback.xml` or you include the log4j libs. (when you need more help with including the lib then please post your pom.xml)

*I reccomend to use logback (and slf4j)*

---

**OLD:**

- put the `log4j.properties` file in `src\main\resources` (not in `...\java`)
- make sure that it is named `log4j.properties` (in your question you named the file `log4j.propertie`)
- add this lines to your `web.xml`

web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

(@see [Initializing Log4J with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4400583/280244))

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the questions, I did add what you refer in my web.xml, but no luck. Also, I am using spring boot as well as spring mvc, so actually, I do not put anything special in the web.xml, I run the app with an Application.java

Comment: @Jaskey did you figure this out? I am facing the same issue with spring-boot.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem, it turned out that spring boot includes Spring Boot Starter Logging and will ignore anything you add while that is still there. I was able to fix it by double clicking on my pom and clicking on Spring-Boot-Starter-Logging and then selecting "edit starters" then removing the spring boot starter logging.

If you are using some other kind of dependency management system the idea is the same, just carefully review anything that spring boot included in your project and make sure that log4J is the only logging system included.

Answer (score 0):

First create log4j2-apring.xml in resources dir.
second exclude default sprint bood logback from starter in pom.xml then add log4j starter to po.xml.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).