# Custom log4j.properties location for Spring web application

Tags: spring, logging, configuration, configuration-files

Is it possible to provide custom location for the log4j.properties file for the log4j 1.x?
I don't want to include the file in the project's resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure the `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` in your [`web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400664/280244) with context-parameter `log4jConfigLocation`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:C:/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

[Log4jConfigListener JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html):

> Bootstrap listener for custom log4j initialization in a web environment. Delegates to `Log4jWebConfigurer`...

---

[Log4jWebConfigurer JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html):

> Location of the log4j config file; either a "classpath:" location
>   (e.g. "classpath:myLog4j.properties"), an absolute file URL (e.g.
>   "file:C:/log4j.properties), or a plain path relative to the web
>   application root directory (e.g. "/WEB-INF/log4j.properties"). If not
>   specified, default log4j initialization will apply ("log4j.properties"
>   or "log4j.xml" in the class path; see the log4j documentation for
>   details). "log4jRefreshInterval":

Comment: Thanks Ralph. If I want to configure the file location programmatically, should I inject a custom Log4jWebConfigurer implementation?